# How to align image flush with text

Tags: html

I'm trying to place icon next to text using span but the images are not flush with the text that is beside them. They are moved up. I'm wondering if anyone knows why it is displayed this way and how to fix it. Thanks you.

```
<div class="search" id="search">
  <input type="search" placeholder="What can we help you find today?"><span>
  <img src="search.png" width="20" height="20"></span>
</div>

<div class="customer" id="customer">
  <div class="My Account">
    <p>My Account<span><img src="user.png" width="23" height="23"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="cart">
    <span>Cart |</span><span>0</span><span>items</span><span>
    <img src="cart.png" width="23" height="auto"></span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Browser Display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the default vertical alignment for inline elements is baseline. Set the alignment on your images to middle> Also be sure to remove any white space in your code that would be between those elements as browsers are sensitive to it:

```
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="search" id="search">
  <input type="search" placeholder="What can we help you find today?"><span><img src="search.png" width="20" height="20"></span>
</div>

<div class="customer" id="customer">
  <div class="My Account">
    <p>My Account<span><img src="user.png" width="23" height="23"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="cart">
    <span>Cart |</span><span>0</span><span>items</span><span><img src="cart.png" width="23" height="auto"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep that was my problem...Thanks a lot